# Flex 3 DataGrid Tab Order

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, datagrid, mxml

I've been trying to get the tab order to work on this datagrid for some time now and I can't figure out what I am doing wrong.  Can anyone spot it?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<controls:MDataGrid xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" 
                xmlns:controls="com.iwobanas.controls.*" 
                xmlns:dgc="com.iwobanas.controls.dataGridClasses.*"
                dataProvider="{locator.vendorInvoices}">

<mx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import com.model.PayablesLocator;

        [Bindable] private var locator:PayablesLocator = PayablesLocator.getInstance();
    ]]>
</mx:Script>

<controls:columns>

    <dgc:MDataGridColumn dataField="loadNumber" 
                         headerText="Load"/>

    <dgc:MDataGridColumn dataField="carrierName" 
                         headerText="Carrier"/>

    <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="vendorInvoiceNumber" 
                       headerText="Vendor Invoice #"
                       rendererIsEditor="true"
                       editorDataField="vendorInvoiceNumber">
        <mx:itemRenderer>
            <mx:Component>
                <mx:HBox width="100%" height="100%" horizontalAlign="center" verticalAlign="middle">                        

                    <mx:Script>
                        <![CDATA[
                            protected function invoiceNumberInput_changeHandler(event:Event):void {
                                data.vendorInvoiceNumber = invoiceNumberInput.text;
                            }
                        ]]>
                    </mx:Script>

                    <mx:TextInput id="invoiceNumberInput"
                                  text="{data.vendorInvoiceNumber}"
                                  editable="true"
                                  width="95%"
                                  change="invoiceNumberInput_changeHandler(event)"/>
                </mx:HBox>
            </mx:Component>
        </mx:itemRenderer>
    </mx:DataGridColumn>

    <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="vendorInvoiceDate" 
                       headerText="Invoice Date"
                       rendererIsEditor="true"
                       editorDataField="vendorInvoiceDate">
        <mx:itemRenderer>
            <mx:Component>
                <mx:HBox width="100%" height="100%" horizontalAlign="center" verticalAlign="middle">

                    <mx:Script>
                        <![CDATA[
                            import mx.controls.Alert;
                            import mx.events.CalendarLayoutChangeEvent;
                            import mx.events.CloseEvent;

                            protected function invoiceDateChanged(event:CalendarLayoutChangeEvent):void {
                                data.vendorInvoiceDate = event.newDate;
                            }
                        ]]>
                    </mx:Script>

                    <mx:DateField id="vendorInvoiceDateInput"
                                  selectedDate="{data.vendorInvoiceDate}"
                                  editable="true"
                                  width="95%"
                                  change="invoiceDateChanged(event)"/>                      
                </mx:HBox>

            </mx:Component>
        </mx:itemRenderer>
    </mx:DataGridColumn>

    <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="isSelected"
                       headerText="Select" 
                       rendererIsEditor="true"
                       editorDataField="isSelected">
        <mx:itemRenderer>
            <mx:Component>
                <mx:HBox horizontalAlign="center" verticalAlign="middle">                       

                    <mx:Script>
                        <![CDATA[
                            import com.controller.PayablesController;

                            private var control:PayablesController = PayablesController.getInstance();

                            private function onCheckboxClick():void {

                                data.isSelected = selectionCheckBox.selected;
                                control.updateBatchSelections();
                            }
                        ]]>
                    </mx:Script>    

                    <mx:CheckBox id="selectionCheckBox"
                                 selected="{data.isSelected}"
                                 change="onCheckboxClick()"/>
                </mx:HBox>
            </mx:Component>
        </mx:itemRenderer>
    </mx:DataGridColumn>

</controls:columns>
```

I'm trying to get the tab order as follows for each row: Vendor Invoice > Invoice Date > Select, but when I try to tab to the next field it jumps to the URL of the browser (IE in this case).  I've tried a bunch of things found on the net, but none of them have seemed to work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

--Charly

Comment: Hi Charly, can you list a few things you've tried (tabIndex is the first that comes to mind for me) also when posting questions about custom components, please include a link to the API, I found this one which I believe is what you're using, but makes it easier for everyone if we don't have to search http://reusable-fx.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/com/iwobanas/controls/MDataGrid.html

Comment: Ah also I think I know why what I suggested won't work and why probably other stuff you've tried doesn't work.  The DataGridColumn and other grid column classes are basically model objects for describing the UI components that need to be created dynamically for a grid, so you're not really defining the UIComponents directly using those tags, but rather giving it the description of how to create them when it needs them.  So you probably need to handle this by looking at making custom headerRenderer objects that set the tabIndex on each instance appropriately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no built in support for this. This will work if you have editable cells, and that too it will only work if your editors implement IFocusManagerComponent. (In this case your editors are wrapped inside HBoxes which do not). If you were using the spark datagrid, you could use : http://squaredi.blogspot.com/2011/09/precision-focus-control-within-spark.html

Comment: Thanks Flexicious.  This is what I was able to eventually get working.  Looks like it will be nice when our shop can eventually move to Spark.

Comment: No problem. FYI, it is not necessary to wrap your editors within HBoxes, especially since you only have one control inside the HBox. So you could just use <mx:itemRenderer> <mx:Component> <mx:TextInput ... and not have to implement IFocusManagerComponent since TextInput already does that. Also, don't be too excited about moving to Spark. It comes with its own set of issues :-). Best scenario is that you can use both Spark and Halo as appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Resulting working code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<controls:MDataGrid xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" 
                xmlns:controls="com.iwobanas.controls.*" 
                xmlns:dgc="com.iwobanas.controls.dataGridClasses.*"
                dataProvider="{locator.vendorInvoices}"
                editable="true">

<mx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import com.model.PayablesLocator;

        [Bindable] private var locator:PayablesLocator = PayablesLocator.getInstance();
    ]]>
</mx:Script>

<controls:columns>

    <dgc:MDataGridColumn dataField="loadNumber" 
                         headerText="Load"
                         editable="false"/>

    <dgc:MDataGridColumn dataField="carrierName" 
                         headerText="Carrier"
                         editable="false"/>

    <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="vendorInvoiceNumber" 
                       headerText="Vendor Invoice #"
                       rendererIsEditor="true"
                       editorDataField="value">
        <mx:itemRenderer>
            <mx:Component>
                <mx:HBox width="100%" height="100%" horizontalAlign="center" verticalAlign="middle"
                         implements="mx.managers.IFocusManagerComponent">                       

                    <mx:Script>
                        <![CDATA[
                            [Bindable] public var value:String;

                            override public function drawFocus(draw:Boolean):void {
                                invoiceNumberInput.setFocus();
                            }
                        ]]>
                    </mx:Script>

                    <mx:TextInput id="invoiceNumberInput"
                                  text="{value}"
                                  width="95%"/>

                </mx:HBox>
            </mx:Component>
        </mx:itemRenderer>
    </mx:DataGridColumn>

    <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="vendorInvoiceDate" 
                       headerText="Invoice Date"
                       rendererIsEditor="true"
                       editorDataField="value">
        <mx:itemRenderer>
            <mx:Component>
                <mx:HBox width="100%" height="100%" horizontalAlign="center" verticalAlign="middle"
                         implements="mx.managers.IFocusManagerComponent">                       

                    <mx:Script>
                        <![CDATA[
                            [Bindable] public var value:Date;

                            override public function drawFocus(draw:Boolean):void {
                                vendorInvoiceDateInput.setFocus();
                            }
                        ]]>
                    </mx:Script>

                    <mx:DateField id="vendorInvoiceDateInput"
                                  selectedDate="{value}"
                                  editable="true"
                                  width="95%"/>

                </mx:HBox>
            </mx:Component>
        </mx:itemRenderer>
    </mx:DataGridColumn>

    <mx:DataGridColumn editorDataField="isSelected"
                       headerText="Select"
                       rendererIsEditor="true">         
        <mx:itemRenderer>
            <mx:Component>

                <mx:HBox width="100%" height="100%" horizontalAlign="center" verticalAlign="middle"
                         implements="mx.controls.listClasses.IDropInListItemRenderer,mx.managers.IFocusManagerComponent">

                    <mx:Script>
                        <![CDATA[
                            import com.controller.PayablesController;

                            import mx.controls.dataGridClasses.DataGridListData;
                            import mx.controls.listClasses.BaseListData;

                            private var control:PayablesController = PayablesController.getInstance();

                            private var _listData:DataGridListData;
                            [Bindable] public var isSelected:Boolean;

                            override public function drawFocus(draw:Boolean):void {
                                selectionCheckBox.setFocus();
                            }

                            override public function get data():Object {
                                return super.data;

                            }   

                            override public function set data(value:Object):void {
                                super.data = value;
                                selectionCheckBox.selected = data.isSelected
                            }

                            public function get listData():BaseListData {
                                return _listData;
                            }   

                            public function set listData(value:BaseListData):void {
                                _listData = DataGridListData(value);
                            }

                            protected function onChange(event:Event):void {
                                data.isSelected = selectionCheckBox.selected;
                                control.updateBatchSelections();
                            }                               
                        ]]>
                    </mx:Script>  

                    <mx:CheckBox id="selectionCheckBox" change="onChange(event)"/>

                </mx:HBox>

            </mx:Component>
        </mx:itemRenderer>
    </mx:DataGridColumn>

</controls:columns>
```